# USER_ENTER_ROOM event is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, smartfoxserver

I am working on unity with smartfox integration for my multi player cards game. Now I am creating rooms to join to play the game. Room is created and user is joined in the room, the problem is now I have to call USER_ENTER_ROOM event to confirm that user is entered in the room and no room creation error occurred. But this event is not givin the Logs. I have tried this

```
public void OnUserEnterRoom(BaseEvent evt){
    User user = (User)evt.Params["user"];
    Room room = (Room)evt.Params["room"];
    Debug.Log("User: " + user.Name + " has just joined Room: " + room.Name);
}
```

and I called this event in my awake function like this.

```
sfs.AddEventListener(SFSEvent.USER_ENTER_ROOM, OnUserEnterRoom);
```

According to my r&d it should work but its not.

Comment: Whilst you may get an answer on SO there is also a GameDevelopment stack exchange where there may be more unity users.. I'd suggest trying there if you are unable to get help on here

Comment: Oky gonna post there.

Answer (score 0):

The [`USER_ENTER_ROOM`](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/api-docs/csharp-doc/?topic=html/1d26b810-aecb-3f57-a1a8-7074fe66da32.htm) event doesn't fire if you enter the room, but when another user enters a room you have already joined.

To confirm that you have joined the room and no error occurred you have to listen to [`ROOM_JOIN`](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/api-docs/csharp-doc/?topic=html/ced4bdcf-f93c-7d63-e33f-967045fbea46.htm) and [`ROOM_JOIN_ERROR`](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/api-docs/csharp-doc/?topic=html/ced4bdcf-f93c-7d63-e33f-967045fbea46.htm).

If you need to create the room you can monitor [`ROOM_ADD`](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/api-docs/csharp-doc/?topic=html/672a44e4-f86d-c9ea-f236-8542a86e49a1.htm) and [`ROOM_CREATION_ERROR`](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/api-docs/csharp-doc/?topic=html/da42a909-f66c-5ec0-202c-679f37cd54f1.htm)

Have a look at this tutorial: http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/DevelopmentBasics/join-and-create-rooms

Comment: Yup I did the same to get of that problem. Thanks a lot for your response.